# Create custom token for admin sdk using seed value from Firestore database?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am generating a device specific unique ID value and am storing it inside a document within my Firestore database.  I would like to be able to use this value as a seed for a custom token that would allow a device to authenticate using this same unique ID.  Is there a way to do this without hosting the Firebase Admin SDK on a separate server?  I'd like to be able to use it with existing Google cloud services (preferably directly in Firestore).  I'd like to avoid Google Cloud Functions as cold start delays could be problematic with authentication.

Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Tag your question only with relevant tags please. I removed the `firebase-realtime-database` tag, since you make no mention of it anywhere. I also wonder what this has to do with `android` though.

Comment: There is no way to run code inside the Firestore database, aside from the (side-effect free) security rules. Since you already seem to know Cloud Functions, but don't want to use them, this is essentially a request for a technology recommendation, which is off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the response Frank.  Since the Admin SDK is part of Firebase that's why I added Firebase (sorry if I was wrong on that one).  Android tag because my client app is Android (sorry I forgot to mention that).  From your answer if I understand you correctly, it sounds like Cloud Functions are what I'll have to use.  Am I correct?

Comment: The Admin SDK is to be used in a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions. These last two sound most sensible for your use-case, and cold start time should be quite reasonable these days from what I can see.